# How to italicise multiple words but not the commas between them?

Tags: italic

For example, I have this sentence:

> GeneA, GeneB, and GeneC have been found to have a role in RNA metabolism.

This is what I would like, format-wise:

> *GeneA*, *GeneB*, and *GeneC* have been found to have a role in RNA metabolism.

I can achieve this with:

> \textit{GeneA}, \textit{GeneB}, and \textit{GeneC} have been found to have a role in RNA metabolism.

Is there a way to italicise a list of words, but leaving the comma out as textit also italicises the commas? i.e.

> \italiciselist{GeneA, GeneB}, and \textit{GeneC} have been found to have a role in RNA metabolism.

It's not a problem with 2 or 3 words needing italicising, but when it's longer, it would be much easier with a function which takes more than one word.

Comment: or `\newcommand\z[1]{\textit{Gene#1}}`  then `\z{A}, \z{B}, \z{C}`

Answer (score 3):

From the example below, copy the lines between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` (inclusively) to the preamble of your document. They define your command `\italiciselist`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\italiciselist[1]{%
   \def\il@sep{}%
   \@for\il@gene:=#1\do{%
      \il@sep\textit{\il@gene}%
      \def\il@sep{, }%
   }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\italiciselist{GeneA,GeneB}, and \textit{GeneC} have been found to have a role in RNA metabolism.
\end{document}
```

[image]